# Should I wrap a task in another task or should I just return the created task?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ado.net, task-parallel-library

I'm building a .NET 4.0 application that uses ADO.NET, so I cannot use async/await.
I don't want a solution for that, but I do want to know what of the following implementations is best and why. My unit tests pass for all three implementations, but I want to know the difference between these three.

### #1 Nesting tasks

In my first implementation I wrap a task in another task. I think spinning up two tasks is bad for performance, but I'm not sure.

```c#
public virtual Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(IDbCommand dbCommand, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var sqlCommand = CheckIfSqlCommand(dbCommand);
        PrepareExecuteReader(dbCommand);

        return Task<IDataReader>
            .Factory
            .FromAsync(sqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader, sqlCommand.EndExecuteReader, null)
            .Result;
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

### #2 Using TaskCompletionSource

Then I tried wrapping the result in a `TaskCompletionSource` so I just have one task.

```c#
public virtual Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(IDbCommand dbCommand, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IDataReader>();
    var sqlCommand = CheckIfSqlCommand(dbCommand);
    PrepareExecuteReader(dbCommand);

    var reader = Task<IDataReader>
        .Factory
        .FromAsync(sqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader, sqlCommand.EndExecuteReader, null)
        .Result;

    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(reader);

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

### #3 returning Task directly

My final solution is to directly return the task I created instead of wrapping it.

```c#
public virtual Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(IDbCommand dbCommand, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var sqlCommand = CheckIfSqlCommand(dbCommand);
    PrepareExecuteReader(dbCommand);

    return Task<IDataReader>
        .Factory
        .FromAsync(sqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader, sqlCommand.EndExecuteReader, null);
}
```

#### So basically my question is:

What option should I use or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Targeting .Net 4.0 doesn't necessarily mean you can't use async-await. You can use it if you add Microsoft.Bcl.Async to your project, though it requires VS 2012.

Comment: Developers should be able to use vs2010 also, but I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #3 is the best. The first two introduce complication for no reason.

1 potentially adds another thread purely to run `CheckIfSqlCommand()` and `PrepareExecuteReader()` asynchronously. This may be what you wanted, but they don't sound like commands that are going to take a long time.

2 references `.Result` of the task, which will block until the task is complete, so defeats the whole purpose of using tasks.

Comment: I wonder if there are situations where you don't use tasks for I/O or networking. If there are, how do I know when to use asynchronicity?

Comment: @annemartijn if you have to ask, don't use async. Use it when you must.

Answer (score -1):

There are two scenes we use asynchronous programming with `Tasks`, one is massive computing, another is `I/O`.
In massive computing situation, we always use `Task.Run` to ask a thread from thread pool to avoid blocking thread.
In `I/O` situation, if `async` api is not provided, we always use `TaskCompletionSource` or `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to build an `async` method. I think mix these two is not a good solution.
By the way, `Task.Run` is always been used in client application, server end generally not used `Task.Run` due to concurrent request.
Here is a good post you can refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/september/async-tasks-simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-tasks